# Django-tutorial. The counter is not change

Tags: python, django

Good day! There was a question on the tutorial documentation from Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/
My choice of the counter does not respond to the results of the voting by pressing the button displays a message vote "You did not select a choice."
and the voice is not taken , I can not understand in what a piece of code error, tell me, please.

as I understand, all handle exceptions

File views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

    from django.views import generic

    from .models import Choice, Question

    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        template_name = 'polls/index.html'
        context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

        def get_queryset(self):
            """Return the last five published questions."""
            return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

    class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Question
        template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Question
        template_name = 'polls/results.html'

    def vote(request, question_id):
        p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        print(request.POST)
        try:
            selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
        except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist) as e:
            print(e)
            # Redisplay the question voting form.
            return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
                'question': p,
                'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
            })
        else:
            selected_choice.votes += 1
            selected_choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

file polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

file detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

UPD:

Terminal output:

```
[06/Sep/2015 18:45:05] "GET /polls/3/vote/ HTTP/1.1" 200 255
[06/Sep/2015 18:45:09] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 200 130
[06/Sep/2015 18:48:25] "GET /polls/3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 200
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['8L4m4ziCq9k9jRQzFeoCtJ8NLjq1qn8j']}>
"'choice'"
[06/Sep/2015 18:48:26] "POST /polls/3/vote/ HTTP/1.1" 200 255
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['8L4m4ziCq9k9jRQzFeoCtJ8NLjq1qn8j']}>
"'choice'"
[06/Sep/2015 18:48:53] "POST /polls/3/vote/ HTTP/1.1" 200 255
```

UPD2:

view-source:http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/3/vote/

```
<h1>Test1</h1>

<p><strong>You didn&#39;t select a choice.</strong></p>

<form action="/polls/3/vote/" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='8L4m4ziCq9k9jRQzFeoCtJ8NLjq1qn8j' />

<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please double check if your `polls/detail.html` file is exactly like the one in the tutorial. Either way please post it here, too.

Comment: I can't immediately spot the problem. To help debug, you could add `print(request.POST)` before the `try:` line, and let us know what is printed. You could also change the except line to `except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist) as e:`, then add `print(e)` on the next line.

Comment: Nothing. Again "You did not select a choice."  upper vote-button

Comment: When I say 'let us know what is printed', I mean in the terminal where you have done `./manage.py runserver`. I would expect `print(request.POST)` to show something - even if it's empty you should see `{}`.

Comment: It might also be helpful if you show the rendered html for your detail template (you can get this by selecting something like 'View Page Source' in your browser).

Comment: ./manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 06, 2015 - 18:43:23
Django version 1.8.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: The print statements will appear in the terminal when you click submit the form.

Comment: UPD post. Terminal's result

Comment: OK, so the terminal output shows that the choice is not being submitted, so the problem might be in your template. Could you add your rendered template as I asked above? Forgive the simple question, but are you certain that you are selecting a choice before pressing submit?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe my form has the wrong appearance. Lesson hasn't screenshots. That my list screenshot http://i.imgur.com/O6LwsRr.png

Comment: That screenshot is for the list of polls, the page we are interested in is voting page, e.g. `/polls/3/vote/`. We need to see the **html** (click View Page Source or similar), not the screenshot.

Comment: UPD2 post. Page source 127.0.0.1:8000/polls/3/vote/

Comment: It doesn't look as if the question you've chosen has any choices... Do you have any radio buttons displayed on your form? Your HTML output suggests not. If your question has no choices, you won't be able to select a choice...

Comment: Ok, how can add the radiobutton? it's only tutorial

Answer (score 4):

This is because you do not have any "choices" in the question. Probable you don't execute the complete example code in part 2.

[image]